# Required Android Browser Text

Tags: android, android-browser

I have some requirement where I want to get using INTENT, what url is entered in the Android Browser and to display it in my application.

For your kind notice I have already checked the whole stackoverflow and have not got any relevant answer.

Please help me if anybody can. Please dont vote down if you don't understand my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only access the browsing history but you cannot directly access the URL. In order to access the history, you need to add the persmission com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS to execute the following code for fetching the history.

The code given above is very correct. You can use that. In case of any problem you can ask me again, then I will tell you some other means to achieve the same. 
First do with this code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can access the browsing history but you cannot directly access the URL. In order to access the history, you need to add the persmission `com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS` to execute the following code for fetching the history.

```
Cursor webLinksCursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " DESC");
int row_count = webLinksCursor.getCount();

int title_column_index = webLinksCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE);
int url_column_index = webLinksCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL);

if ((title_column_index > -1) && (url_column_index > -1) && (row_count > 0))
{
webLinksCursor.moveToFirst();
while (webLinksCursor.isAfterLast() == false)
{
    if (webLinksCursor.getInt(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_BOOKMARK_INDEX) != 1)
    {
        if (!webLinksCursor.isNull(url_column_index))
        {
            Log.i("History" , "Last page browsed " + webLinksCursor.getString(url_column_index));
            break;
        }
    }
    webLinksCursor.moveToNext();
}            
}
webLinksCursor.close();
```

HISTORY_PROJECTION_BOOKMARK_INDEX is used for distinguishing among the bookmarks.

Hope this helps.